# Android is there a method similar to onListClickView for CheckBoxs?

Tags: android

So my question is the title: Android is there a method similar to onListClickView for CheckBoxs?

I have a method onListClickView to get the place where the list has been touched and get the information from that slot in the list.

```
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
    TextView label = ((TwoLineListItem) v).getText2();
    String phoneNumber = label.getText().toString();
    Toast.makeText(this, "Selected " + phoneNumber, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

This is the method that i have but i am unaware of something similar that i could use for getting this same information for the boxes checked. Can anyone shed some light on this issue that I have?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can listen for the checkbox being clicked:

```
CheckBox check = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.check_box);
check.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    @Override public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton button, boolean isChecked) {
        // The checkbox has been clicked - do something interesting
    }
});
```

Comment: This would allow me to see if the check box is being checked but does not tell which check box is being checked. Which is what i need to retrieve the phone number from the corresponding text there.

Comment: This is close enough though to what i want to get. i believe i can look around the web for the function to get the line position of the checkbox. Thank you